# ListView or Table in Google Glass

Tags: android, list, google-glass

My question is how to create a list on google glass card like below -

```
                13:45

--------------------------------------
Name           Address          Date 
---------------------------------------- 
Rakesh         Bangalore      12/1/2014
----------------------------------------
Rajesh         Delhi          13/1/2014 
----------------------------------------
Suresh         NY             14/1/2014
----------------------------------------
```

is any way to create List or ListView or Table or TableView like above ?

Comment: Damn... are you coding for google glass? ...lucky

Comment: Yes, Srikanth, but facing lots of issue. If you have any exposure please let me know. Basically creatign a List, or table inside a timeline or card.

Comment: dir you get a solution on this one ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ListView directly. It scrolls and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your cards will be used. 
If it's a live card (frequently/infrequently-changing content), you can use a ListView, as @jrharshath pointed out.

If you are sending info from a web app, you can use the Mirror API. After extracting data for your table from a database, you can format a table in HTML and push to Glass.

Answer (score 0):

Create Table Layout

```
<TableLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:shrinkColumns="*"  android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#ffffff">


 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="row1"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#dcdcdc" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="373.175"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#d3d3d3" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#cac9c9" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dip" android:gravity="center"/>
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
         android:text="row2"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#dcdcdc" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
         android:text="0"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#d3d3d3" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
         android:text="0"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#cac9c9" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dip" android:gravity="center"/>
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="row3"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#dcdcdc" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#d3d3d3" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#cac9c9" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dip" android:gravity="center"/>
 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Call it setContentView(R.layout.table_layout);L